# OSX Apple Magic Mouse disconnects

Tags: macos, mouse, bluetooth

I'm having constant disconnects/reconnect on my Apple Magic Mouse (bluetooth).

... following output from Console.app:

```
4/1/13 8:29:06.000 PM kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchDevice::willTerminate] entered
4/1/13 8:29:06.000 PM kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchDevice::stop] entered
4/1/13 8:29:08.000 PM kernel[0]: [BNBMouseDevice::init][75.19] init is complete
4/1/13 8:29:08.000 PM kernel[0]: [BNBMouseDevice::handleStart][75.19] returning 1
4/1/13 8:29:08.000 PM kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchHIDEventDriver::start] entered
4/1/13 8:29:08.000 PM kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchDevice::start] entered
```

I've tried making it *favorite* and/or removing *com.apple.Bluetooth.plist* yet still no such luck! any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Just wondering: a) do you have a bluetooth keyboard, and is it encountering the same problems; b) have you tried connecting the bluetooth mouse to another device and does it then still has these problems?

Comment: i do have bluetooth keyboard and it doesn't look like problem is present w/ keyboard, i have not tried connecting mouse to another computer but about too)

Answer (score -1):

Try doing the following steps.  This will cause a PRAM reset.

> 1. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
> 2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Option, Command (⌘), P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step 4.
> 3. Turn on your Mac.
> 4. Immediately press and hold the Option-Command-P-R keys. You must press this key combination before the gray screen appears.
> 5. Continue holding the keys down until your Mac restarts, and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
> 6. Release the keys.

[source](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761?locale=en_US)

Comment: `OS X Yosemite` nor devices with `PRAM` was _NOT_ available back in `Apr 2 '13`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.